# Make Tkinter Label Handle from variable function input?

Tags: python, tkinter

Python 3

I want to create a Tkinter label with a handle name that is passed from a function. For example, if the variable name is 'hotdog', I want to create a label that is called 'hotdogLabel', that displays the value of hotdog. I made a function that creates the label, but I dont know how to script the variable input.  This does not work

```
def makeLabel(labelname,width,gridx,gridy,px,py):
    name=labelname+'label'
    name =Label(window,text=labelname,width=width).grid(row=gridx,column=gridy,padx=px,pady=py)

window = tk.Tk()
makeLabel('FOOBAR',25,1,2,5,5)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Even if your attempt at making a dynamically-generated variable name had worked, it wouldn't have accomplished anything since it was a local variable, nonexistent outside of the function.  Just return the new `Label`, and let the caller assign it to whatever variable name they want (or append it to a list, or anything else they might want to do).

Comment: Why do you think you need to create a variable with a passed-in name? What problem does that solve?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't assign the value to text you used the old value.

```
def makeLabel(labelname,width,gridx,gridy,px,py):
    name=labelname+'label'
    name =Label(window,text=name,width=width).grid(row=gridx,column=gridy,padx=px,pady=py)

window = tk.Tk()
makeLabel('FOOBAR',25,1,2,5,5)
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I could think of is to use a dictionary to store a key with the name you want, and the corresponding Label object.

Building on top of your example:

```
def main():
    def makeLabel(labeltext,width,gridx,gridy,px,py):
        # dynamically created label name
        labelname=labeltext+'label'

        # creates Label object and store reference to it in 'label'
        label = tk.Label(window, text=labelname,width=width)

        # places label on grid
        label.grid(row=gridx,column=gridy,padx=px,pady=py)

        # returns tuple with label name and Label object
        return (labelname, label)

    window = tk.Tk()

    # initialize dictionary
    labelDictionary = {}

    # newLblEntry will receive a tuple ('FOOBARlabel', <reference to Label object>)
    newLblEntry = makeLabel('FOOBAR',25,1,2,5,5)

    # store Label object with the key 'FOOBARlabel'
    labelDictionary[newLblEntry[0]] = newLblEntry[1]

    window.mainloop()
```

By doing this, when you need to get the Label created above, simply do `Label label = labelDictionary['FOOBARlabel']`.

Good link for more on python dictionaries:
http://www.compciv.org/guides/python/fundamentals/dictionaries-overview